# Using auth_token from request headers instead from POST/PUT parameters with Rails 3 / devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

I need to use token based authentication in a Rails 3.1 API in conjunction with the most recent version of devise. No problem so far.

Now I do not want to append my :auth_token to the POST/PUT parameters on client side but send this token as a request header like HTTP_X_MYAPP_AUTH_TOKEN".

Can I convince devise from using that rather than a token from parameters? Is it possible to implement both, so that my API users can send the token via request header OR POST/PUT parameter?

Regards. Felix

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the same need and came up with this solution:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_filter :get_api_key
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  private
  def get_api_key
    if api_key = params[:api_key].blank? && request.headers["X-API-KEY"]
      params[:api_key] = api_key
    end
  end
end
```

Note I have my devise `Devise.token_authentication_key` set to `api_key`.

```
config.token_authentication_key = :api_key
```

Comment: Hey Chris, nice Solution, like that. I created my own patch for devise meanwhile, works too. Your Solutions seems to be a nice fit for everyone coming accross the same problem in the future.

Comment: Hmm doesn't work for me :-/

```get_api_key``` is correctly executed before ```authenticate_user!``` but sadly by this time Warden Rack middleware has already parsed params on its own and has own copy of params that won't notice added :api_key item.

Comment: Nice idea, but I think I'm having the same problem as @WojtekKruszewski

Comment: Same thing here. Was anybody able to have this working with the latest Devise?

Comment: Same problem! The parameter isn't added as it should.

Comment: Same issue here, anyone with a good solution? (Rails 4, devise 3)

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a custom "strategy" for this: https://gist.github.com/4492569

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in Devise to pass a standard authentication token through query string or the header for HTTP Basic Authentication, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360853/using-basic-auth-to-pass-authentication-token/15361473). The Ruby code from the specs to pass token in the HTTP_Authorization header is

```
header = "Basic #{Base64.encode64("#{VALID_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN}:X")}"
get users_path(:format => :xml), {}, "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" => header
```

Testing from the command line with curl would go like this:

```
echo  "HUGP59gXsd7773a75Dvc:X" | base64
=> SFVHUDU5Z1hzZDc3NzNhNzVEdmM6WAo=
curl --header "Authorization: Basic SFVHUDU5Z1hzZDc3NzNhNzVEdmM6WAo=" \ 
     http://localhost/users.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Using devise and devise-token_authenticatable, I had to set this in my config/initializers/devise.rb in order to pass the token via http headers:

`config.http_authenticatable = true`