# How to config devise to accept auth token in HTTP header?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Currently, [devise](http://rubygems.org/gems/devise) is configured to accept token authentication via URL and curl works well

```
curl 'http://localhost/index.json?auth_token=TOKENVALUE'
```

Now I'd like to pass the TOKENVALUE via HTTP header instead of URL, how can I config devise to get the TOKENVALUE from *either* HTTP header *or* URL? Such that both the above and following curl requests will work:

```
curl 'http://localhost/index.json' -H 'Authorization: Token token="TOKENVALUE"'
```

as shown in [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast).

Answer (score 1):

It seems there isn't such config in devise. But there is a solution by other person. Please see [Using auth_token from request headers instead from POST/PUT parameters with Rails 3 / devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399645)

Answer (score 1):

First add this to your gemfile https://github.com/stvp/devise_header_token then you can add a configuration for it in your config/initializers/devise.rb

```
# Configuration for :token_authenticatable
# Defines name of the authentication token params key
config.token_authentication_key = 'AUTH-TOKEN'
```

Answer (score 1):

Devise allows auth token authentication via Basic Auth. If you look the [source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/token_authenticatable.rb) you'll see this:

> For headers, you can use basic authentication passing the token as username and
>   blank password. Since some clients may require a password, you can pass "X" as
>   password and it will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed since this question was asked, in that devise no longer has the token authentication functionality built-in. It was extracted out to a separate gem, devise-token_authenticatable. I am using that gem and wanted to do the same the same thing as the person who asked the question.

I figured out I had to set this in my config/initializers/devise.rb:

`config.http_authenticatable = true`

I tried it via curl and it worked. In my RSpec tests I was able to put the token in the HTTP header like this:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
header = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(
  user.authentication_token)
get "/api/v1/your_url", 
    { },
    { 
      'Accept' => 'application/json',
      'Authorization' => header
    }
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

Support has been in added to Devise 2.2.4
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rdoc#224